# How to POST GMT Date via Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an issue while POSTing a Date object to my API via Typescript, the selected date from Dropdown is a GMT date, like `Fri Sep 25 2020 18:30:00 GMT+0200` but when the date is going to be posted, in the request the date is sent as `2020-09-25T16:30:00.000Z` so in the DB i'm inserting a date with two hours of difference...

Which would be the right approach to send a GMT date via .POST?

The `date` is parsed from an Angular Reactive Form

Answer (score 0):

They are the same:

`2020-09-25T16:30:00.000Z` is the datetime as string in ISO format

`Fri Sep 25 2020 18:30:00 GMT+0200` represents the same datetime as string in a specified timezone